# Assigning values to the elements of a bundle by parsing a file

Tags: scala, chisel

Disclaimer: The following question is going to be in the Chisel-2 semantics as our codebase is still in the transition phase.

I am trying to implement a script in Scala/Chisel which will read some configuration data from a text file and assign it to an appropriate bundle.

Imagine the bundle to be something like:

```
class b1 extends Bundle{
  e1 = UInt(width=x)
  e2 = UInt(width=y)
  e3 = new b2            // b2 is another bundle with elements f1,f2 
}
```

And the text file can have the configuration data in the following manner:

```
b1.e2    = 2
b1.e1    = 3
b1.e3.f1 = 5
b1.e3.f2 = 6
```

I am planning to read the file line-by-line and use regular expressions to first find the corresponding bundle and then the element inside the bundle to assign the value to.

For this purpose, I need some sort of a map of the bundle (b1 and b2 in this case). Once I identify which bundle it is then I further need to identify which element do I have to assign the value to.

So, my questions are:

Is there a way to obtain such a map for the bundles in Chisel?

And, has anyone tried doing anything similar to what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: Do you want all instances of a Bundle to get the same initialization values, or do you want to specify the initialization of each instance that's created?

Comment: The bundles I am referring to are used for configuring a module. So they won't be having multiple instantiations at the same time, but they will need to be assigned with new values after a certain number of clock cycles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bundles have a field [`elements`](https://chisel.eecs.berkeley.edu/api/latest/chisel3/core/Bundle.html#elements:scala.collection.immutable.ListMap[String,chisel3.core.Data]) that returns `ListMap[String, Data]` where the keys are the names of the fields and the values are the `Chisel` `Data` elements. You can use this map not only to inspect what the fields of the Bundle are, but to connect to some of them, eg.

```
b1.elements("e3").elements("f1") := 5.U
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It is exactly what I was looking for. I have just another query. If one of the elements in the bundle is a `Vec (say f1 in the above example is a Vec)`, so will the statement be: `b1.elements("e3").elements("f1").elements(0,1,2....) := 5.U` ?